# Does a weak solution to the geodesic equations coincide with a strong solution?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u^\alpha$ ($\alpha = 0, 1, 2, 3$) is a weak solution to the geodesic equations $u^\alpha(t, x) \partial_\alpha u^\beta(t, x) = -\Gamma^\beta_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu$. By this I mean that $u^\alpha \in C([0, T]; H^3(\mathbb{R}^3))$ and is continuous and solves the equation almost everywhere. Does $u^\alpha$ necessarily coincide with the geodesic vector field $\dot\gamma$ of the metric (which is, say, $C^1$ if the metric is $C^2$)?

Some more details: Here $u^\alpha(t, x)$ is a vector field on spacetime, which we take to be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^3$. It is a weak solution in the sense that
$$
\int_0^T \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \Big( u^\alpha(t, x) \partial_\alpha u^\beta(t, x) + \Gamma^\beta_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu\Big)\psi(t, x)\, dx \, dt = 0
$$
for any $\psi \in C_c^\infty([0, T] \times \mathbb{R}^3; \mathbb{R})$. The initial conditions are a vector field $X$ on $\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}^3$.

On the other hand, we can let $\gamma_x(\tau)$ be the geodesic which at affine parameter $\tau = 0$ is $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and has $\dot\gamma_x(0) = X_x$. Assuming that the geodesics foliate the space nicely (which can be shown via an inverse function theorem), this gives a $C^1$ vector field $v(t, x)$ on spacetime which at $(t, x)$ is the tangent vector to the curve $\gamma$ passing through $(t, x)$.

Are these two vector fields equal?

Comment: What is the role of the parameter $x$?

Comment: I'll edit in some more details - it's a spatial variable (initial point at $t = 0$)

Comment: What’s $H^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$? What regularity are you assuming for $X$?

Comment: $H^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is the third-order $L^2$-based Sobolev space on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e. $u^\alpha$ has weak derivatives of up to third order, each of which are in $L^2$). The initial data $X$ is smooth with compact support.